# How to render the react component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am new to react .I have a javascript map as below

```
{
  {
   key : "Visa",
value : ["10", "20", "30"]   
},

{
   key : "Other",
value : ["30", "40", "50"]   
},
}
```

I have to render the a react component using the above as below :

```
-------------------------
Visa                10 
                    20
                    30

------------------------
Other               30
                    40
                    50
------------------------
```

I am unable to render final result as above using  css and JSX.

Comment: What's the JSX markup you want to achieve?

Comment: As i have shown in the below , I want keys to be show with as first values as row and then only show the value in consecutive rows untill all the values being rendered. and then start with the news keys and values

Comment: Also note that your input data format is very invalid.

Comment: Why do you think that it is inavlid ?

Comment: Because objects need keys. Change it (the outer variable) to an array and it'd work.

Comment: It's not JSON @It'sNotMe.

Comment: Guys, I have made that sample data , because i cant put the actual data here , its a map where value is an array and i have to render that using as show in below , please help me with that rendering part , how to use jsx

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume two things here where the data is correctly formatted since the sample data is incorrectly formatted.

**I. Array of Objects**

```
const data = [
  { key : "Visa", value : ["10", "20", "30"] },
  { key : "Other",value : ["30", "40", "50"] },
]
```

You can map the data while implementing **Flexbox** to align the children.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((el, key) => (
         <div key={key} className="item">
           <div className="item-title">{el.key}</div>
           <div className="item-values">
             {el.values.map((i, key) => (
               <div>{i}</div>
             )}
           </div>
         </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**II. Single Object with multiple keys and values**

```
const data = {
  Visa: ["10", "20", "30"],
  Other: ["30", "40", "50"] 
},
```

You can map the data while implementing **Flexbox** to align the children.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Object.entries(data).map((el, key) => (
         <div key={key} className="item">
           <div className="item-title">{el[0]}</div>
           <div className="item-values">
             {el[1].map((i, key) => (
               <div>{i}</div>
             )}
           </div>
         </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/right-aligned-list-w56yd).

---

Considering your data looks as such:

```
const data = [
  { key: "Visa", value: ["10", "20", "30"] },
  { key: "Other", value: ["30", "40", "50"] }
]
```

You can create a top-level component which takes the `data` array as `props` and iterates over it to render each section. Each section will be another component which takes in the object literal's values as `props`. Here is an example:

```
// This is your top-level component. It iterates over the data array.
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(element => (
        <List key={element.key} 
              title={element.key} 
              values={element.value} 
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

// This is your subcomponent. This one generates the actual HTML.
const List = props => {
  const { title, values } = props;

  return (
    <div className="example-list">
      <div>{title}</div>
      <ul>
        {values.map(value => (
          <li>{value}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then, you can use Flexbox to align the children of `.example-list` left to right. The complete CSS explanation is in the CodeSandbox.